# Can Expression.PropertyOrField be used to access a static property or field?

Tags: c#, .net, expression

The documentation of the `expression` parameter of [`Expression.PropertyOrField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb356180.aspx) states that it can be `null` for static members:

> An Expression whose `Type` contains a property or field named `propertyOrFieldName` . **This can be `null` for static members**.
>   <sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

However, whenever I pass `null` I get an `ArgumentNullException`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation of this method is contradictory:

- The documentation of the `expression` parameter states that it can be `null` for static members
- The documentation of the `ArgumentNullException` states that it is thrown if `expression` is `null`

**Fact is**:
This method can't be used to get access to static members, the documentation of the `expression` parameter is incorrect.
Even when an expression with the correct `Type` is supplied, this method doesn't work as expected, because it only ever looks for instance members.

To access a static field or property, use [`Expression.MakeMemberAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.makememberaccess.aspx) instead.

Comment: Then is that the only difference between PropertyOrField and MakeMemberAccess that the latter allows for static member access? BTW,  doc for MakeMemberAccess is also buggy - it says expression can be null for static members and the exception section says ArgNullException will be thrown if expression is null...

Comment: @KFL **MakeMemberAccess** appears to have been fixed; it now only says an exception is thrown when `member` is `null`. Also, I've filed an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/2449.

Comment: seems like PropertyOrField can access private members whereas MakeMemberAccess cannot